# Tumblr: How to use high-res photos in TEXT posts?

Tags: tumblr, image-scaling

since there is no answer ins similar posts at stackoverflow, I am posting this...

When I post a TEXT post in tumblr, my images get downsized. How can I use the HI-RES of the original photo I upload?

In the template I only see this one, with no hint to photo sizes:

```
{block:Text}
    <section class="content">
        {block:Title}
        <h1>{Title}</h1>
        {/block:Title}
        {Body}
    </section>
{/block:Text}
```

Also the official documentation doesn't help there: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#text-posts

See here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14710157/scale.jpg

Any ideas?

Thank you very much,
rainer

Comment: Same question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35436/high-res-photos-in-text-posts-when-using-tumblr

Comment: That's right, but it was not answered there... Still unresolved :(

Comment: You can't get a higher resolution if you upload the image to Tumblr within a Text post because Tumblr resizes them to be a max of 500px wide.

Comment: That is too bad. I move to wordpress. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer that...

Tumblr resizes images in text posts to max width of 500px. You can't change that.

Comment: I feel your pain, bro. It's 2014 and I ran into this problem, too.

Comment: Add {block:Posts inlineMediaWidth="1280"} as the answer below says.. it works!

Answer (score 3):

Use `{block:Posts inlineMediaWidth="1280"}` and `{/block:Posts}` instead of `{block:Posts}` and `{/block:Posts}`.
See [How to use high resolution photos in text posts in Tumblr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602635/how-to-use-high-resolution-photos-in-text-posts-in-tumblr)